# Magento2 getting following error

Tags: magento2

I created a admin grid but after compilation getting below error

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: XYZ\Giftimport\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 5 passed to XYZ\Giftimport\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface or be null, string given, called in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
Exception in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131
```

Can someone please guide me how to solve this?

```
namespace XYZ\Giftimport\Model\ResourceModel\Grid;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
     /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'code';
    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('XYZ\Giftimport\Model\Gift', 'XYZ\Giftimport\Model\ResourceModel\Gift');
    }

}
```

The above code is of collection.php

```
<?php

namespace XYZ\Giftimport\Model\ResourceModel;

class Gift extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{   
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
     * @param string $connectionName
     */
    // public function __construct(
    //     \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,        
    //     $connectionName = null
    // ) {
    //     parent::__construct($context, $connectionName);
    // }

    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('magento_giftcardaccount_pool', 'code');
    }
    
}
```

Following is the code is XYZ\Giftimport\Model\ResourceModel\Gift

Comment: Share the file __construct() code into the question.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya just added

Comment: Basically I want to show this table data in admin grid magento_giftcardaccount_pool

Comment: share the code of this one  :XYZ\Giftimport\Model\ResourceModel\Gift

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Added code

Comment: try clearing the generated/code and generated/metadata folders

Comment: @Marius I tried not working. Can you please check code once & let me know the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove an old generated files by using command

> sudo bin/magento rm -rf generated/

from the magento root directory, because magento pre-generates all class files with their constructors. Generated classes extends the original classes and used by magento to call a plugins.

After that run the following commands.

> sudo bin/magento c:f